# Mat-table background color on horizontal scroll

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

Using `mat-table` in my angular 6 application, I am not able to set background color for `mat-header-row` and `mat-row` properly on horizontal scroll. CSS property is applied only to visible portion of screen, once scrolled to right, color is not assigned.

[image: Horizonatal Scroll Background Color Issue]

I have around 30 columns in my table, so need horizontal scroll for sure.

**My CSS is as follows:**

```
.mat-toolbar {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: indigo;
    max-height: 12vh;
}

.mat-elevation-z8 {
    padding: 0px;
}

.mat-table {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 68vh;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.mat-header-row {
    position: sticky;
    top: -.5px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 8vh;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: floralwhite;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.mat-row {
    min-height: 8vh;
}

.no-results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.mat-cell {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mat-header-cell {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(1),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 0 0 6%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(2),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 0 0 9%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(3),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 0 0 14%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(4),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(4) {
    flex: 0 0 10%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(5),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(5) {
    flex: 0 0 10%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(6),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(6) {
    flex: 0 0 8%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(7),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(7) {
    flex: 0 0 9%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(8),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(8) {
    flex: 0 0 8%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(9),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(9) {
    flex: 0 0 8%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(10),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(10) {
    flex: 0 0 9%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(11),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(11) {
    flex: 0 0 8%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(12),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(12) {
    flex: 0 0 11%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(13),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(13) {
    flex: 0 0 7%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(14),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(14) {
    flex: 0 0 11%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(15),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(15) {
    flex: 0 0 7%;
}

.mat-cell:nth-child(16),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(16) {
    flex: 0 0 8%;
}

.mat-column-name {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}

.mat-column-position {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}

.mat-column-weight {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}

.mat-column-symbol {
    text-align: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.mat-column-weight {
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

Tried setting overflow property separately to mat-header-row and mat-row; it resolves background color but then header-row and data-rows can be scrolled separately without sync.

**HTML File is as follows:**

```
<div [@routerTransition] class="col-md-12 mat-elevation-z8" class="white-space-pre-line">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        Project Times Overview Report
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <mat-select *ngxPermissionsOnly="['attendance-all-leave-balance-read']" name="year" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear"
            class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Year" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let year of yearName" [value]="year">{{year}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select> &nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" *ngxPermissionsOnly="['attendance-all-leave-balance-read']" [disabled]="selectedYear==''"
            (click)="loadData()">View Report</button>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <div class="form">
        <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never" color="primary">
            <input matInput #filter placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-cell">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="sno">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>S.No.</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport; let i = index;">{{i+1}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="timesCode">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Times Code</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.timesCode}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="projectName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Project</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.projectName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="team">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Team</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{getTeamDesc(timesReport)}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="department">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Department</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{getDeptDesc(timesReport)}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="allocatedWorkload">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Allocated PD</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.allocatedWorkload}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="activity">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Activity</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.activity}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actualWorkload">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Actual Received PD</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.actualWorkload}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="createdBy">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created By</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.createdBy}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="creationDate">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Creation Date</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.creationDate}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="approvedBy">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Approved By</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.approvedBy}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="approvalDate">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Approval Date</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.approvalDate}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="claimed">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Claimed PD</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.claimed}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="unclaimed">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Unclaimed PD</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.unclaimed}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="gapActualAllocated">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Gap (Actual vs Allocated)</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.gapActualAllocated}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lossPD">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Loss PD</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let timesReport">{{timesReport.lossPD}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dispProjectTimesReportColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dispProjectTimesReportColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <div class="no-results" [style.display]="dataSource.renderedData.length == 0 ? '' : 'none'">
        No results found
    </div>

    <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="100"
        [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 200]">
    </mat-paginator>

</div>
```

**Background appears as follows after following Deepu's answer:**
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your template (HTML)?

Comment: @BearNithi Added html template. Please check.

Comment: How about `.mat-row:nth-child(even) td {  background-color: #yourColor;  }`

Comment: Can you create stackblitz example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ShubhamJain, you may just inspect and copy your HTML from the browser, and add it here in a snippet for reproducing your issue with related styles.

Comment: Problem is with matTable mat-row css property. You can create any mat table with some 30 columns so that it spans across screen size. Apply background-color preperty to mat-row and check if it is rendered correctly. I have been facing this issue since a long time.

Comment: Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-qicbs1

Answer (score 7):

### Use this

```
    .mat-header-row{
            width: fit-content !important;
    }
    .mat-row{
            width: fit-content !important;
    }
```

Comment: This still applies at Angular Material 8, and should be the accepted solution.

Comment: This still works on Angular 13...I didn't remember this issue, but why they havent fixed it at source yet??!?! Thanks BTW!

Answer (score 0):

add style to `mat-cell`

```
.mat-row:nth-child(even) .mat-cell{
  background-color: floralwhite;
  min-height: 8vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.mat-row:nth-child(odd) .mat-cell{
  background-color: gainsboro;
  min-height: 8vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.mat-row{
  border-bottom-style: hidden;
}
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-bb44ut?file=app/issue-list/issue-list.component.css)

Comment: Above solution works but applying fixed height to mat-row does not display content properly which is dynamic and can extend more than 8vh. Tried changing height with min-height but that does not work properly.

Comment: does not work properly, it applies background around area having text and it spreads unevenly when content in cells is of varying height. I have attached screenshot in my answer above.